# Beamer - specify logo position in title page

Tags: beamer, positioning, beamer-metropolis

I placed the logo in my title page but I'm not happy with the positioning, I would like it to be at the bottom right, next to author and date.

[image]

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[sectionpage=none, progressbar=frametitle, numbering=fraction]{metropolis}        % Use metropolis theme  
\title{Title}
\date{\today}
\author{Author}
\institute{Title}

% logo of my university
\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{img/politologo.png}} 

\AtBeginSection[]{
\begin{frame}{Talk Overview}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
\frame{\sectionpage}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Comment: Toh, uno del poli! :-)

Answer (score 19, accepted):

The position of the title graphics is determined by the theme. In this case it seems to be placed in the top left side of the slide. A quick (and a bit hacky) way to move it is to put it in a `picture` environment with zero width and height, and then place it where ever you like.

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[sectionpage=none, progressbar=frametitle, numbering=fraction]{metropolis}        % Use metropolis theme  
\title{Title}
\date{\today}
\author{Author}
\institute{Title}

% logo of my university
\titlegraphic{%
  \begin{picture}(0,0)
    \put(305,-120){\makebox(0,0)[rt]{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image}}}
  \end{picture}}
\AtBeginSection[]{
\begin{frame}{Talk Overview}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
\frame{\sectionpage}
}

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

Play with the argument for `\put` to get it where you like.

[image]

Answer (score 12):

Dirty but quick hack: Move the logo right with `\flushright` and down with `\vspace`:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[sectionpage=none, progressbar=frametitle, numbering=fraction]{metropolis}
\title{Title}
\date{\today}
\author{Author}
\institute{Title}

% logo of my university
\titlegraphic{\vspace{4cm}\flushright\includegraphics[width=2cm,height=2cm]{example-image-a}} 

\begin{document}
\maketitle
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\flushright` doesn't seem to have any effect, the logo remains left aligned. I'm compiling with XeLateX if you need the information.

Comment: @AlessandroGaballo: Hm, works for me. But you can replace `\flushright` as well with `\hfill`.

Comment: even \hfill doesn't work but StefanH's answer did the job, thank you in any case!

Answer (score 6):

Just as an idea for future users (but don't accept it as an answers) you can always define your own titleframe and use it as you wish:

```
\documentclass{beamer}
\usetheme[sectionpage=none, progressbar=frametitle, numbering=fraction]{metropolis}        % Use metropolis theme
\usepackage{tikz}


\let\oldtitle\title
\let\oldinstitute\institute
\let\oldauthor\author
\let\olddate\date
\makeatletter
\def\title#1{\xdef\@title{#1}\oldtitle{#1}}
\def\author#1{\xdef\@author{#1}\oldauthor{#1}}
\def\institute#1{\xdef\@institute{#1}\oldinstitute{#1}}
\makeatother

\title{Title}
\date{\today}
\author{Author}
\institute{Title}

\makeatletter
\def\ttlframe{
  \begin{frame}[plain]
    \begin{tikzpicture}
      \node[anchor=west] at (0,-1) {\LARGE\bfseries\@title};

      \draw[orange,thick] (0,-2)--(\textwidth,-2);

      \node[anchor=west] at (0,-3){\@author};
      \node[anchor=west] at (0,-4){\@date};
      \node[anchor=west] at (0,-5){\small\@institute};
      \node[anchor=east,yshift=-0.3cm] at (\textwidth,-4) {\includegraphics[width=2cm]{example-image-a}};
    \end{tikzpicture}
  \end{frame}
}
\makeatother
% logo of my university
%\titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=2cm]{img/politologo.png}} 

\AtBeginSection[]{
\begin{frame}{Talk Overview}
\tableofcontents[currentsection]
\end{frame}
\frame{\sectionpage}
}

\begin{document}
\ttlframe
\end{document}
```

PS: This gives much more flexibility in any case... but the existing answers are closer to the specific question solution.

[image]

PS2: The yshift just shows that you can adjust positioning and I wouldn't really use it.