# add header images to latex using Beamer presentation

Tags: beamer, presentations

am new to Latex and i want to add 2 images at the top of my first frame in latex presentation  [image: this my current presentation]

This the code that i add for the fancyhdr :

```
\documentclass[14pt ,aspectratio = 169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
% \usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage{adjustbox, graphicx}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

%     \begin{figure}[th]
%   \includegraphics[width=3cm]{images/logo-emsi-entry.png}\hfill
%   \includegraphics[width=3cm]{images/osi_logo.jpg}
%   \end{figure} 
%     \vspace{0.5cm}
    
    

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% \fancyhf{}
% \lhead{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{images/logo-emsi-entry.png}}
% \rhead{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{images/osi_logo.jpg}}
% \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}




\title{Réalisation d'une platforme E-commerce}

\author[Name]{Stage de fin d'année\\\vspace{0.4cm}{\small Membre de Jury: Flan \& Fertlan}\\\vspace{0.4cm}}
\vspace{-1.0cm}
\date{Promotion 2021 - 2022}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}[th]
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{images/logo-emsi-entry.png}\hfill
    \includegraphics[width=3cm]{images/osi_logo.jpg}
    \end{figure} 
    \vspace{0.5cm}

\maketitle


\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SE! Please make your code snippet be compilable, then we do not have to guess what you are doing ...

Comment: Sorry , i just edited it.

Answer (score 1):

Don't use `fancyhdr` with beamer, beamer has its own machnism to set head and footlines.

However if you just want to add the image to the first frame, you can place them into the same from as `\titlepage`:

```
\documentclass[14pt ,aspectratio = 169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
% \usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage{adjustbox, graphicx}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}




\title{Réalisation d'une platforme E-commerce}

\author[Name]{Stage de fin d'année\\\vspace{0.4cm}{\small Membre de Jury: Flan \& Fertlan}\\\vspace{0.4cm}}
\vspace{-1.0cm}
\date{Promotion 2021 - 2022}

\begin{document}

\begin{frame}[plain]
\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-duck}\hfill\includegraphics[height=1.5cm]{example-image-duck}
\titlepage
\vfill
\end{frame}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Welcome to TexExchange! The way to put logos on the title page is:

```
    \documentclass[14pt ,aspectratio = 169]{beamer}
\usetheme{Copenhagen}
% \usecolortheme{beaver}
\usepackage{adjustbox, graphicx}
\setbeamertemplate{navigation symbols}{}
\setbeamercovered{transparent}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

    
    \titlegraphic{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{imagew/logo-emsi-entry.png} \hfill  \includegraphics[width=3cm]{images/osi_logo.jpg}} 
    

\usepackage{fancyhdr}
% \fancyhf{}
% \lhead{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{images/logo-emsi-entry.png}}
% \rhead{\includegraphics[width=3cm]{images/osi_logo.jpg}}
% \renewcommand{\headrulewidth}{0.5pt}




\title{Réalisation d'une platforme E-commerce}

\author[Name]{Stage de fin d'année\\\vspace{0.4cm}{\small Membre de Jury: Flan \& Fertlan}\\\vspace{0.4cm}}
\vspace{-1.0cm}
\date{Promotion 2021 - 2022}

\begin{document}


\maketitle


\end{document}
```

But the position of titlegraphic is defined by the theme so, you can find the custom position by using [this solution](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/412707/259954).